# How to get DataArray from CrossFilePicker?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get DataArray from a pdf file on Android using this code -

```
FileData file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

if (file != null)
{
    string fileData = Convert.ToBase64String(file.DataArray);
}
```

file.DataArray brings back an empty array and so the string fileData is empty as well. The file path return works but not DataArray.

I am using Xamarin PCL Project, and the pdf is from a google drive. It works fine with Images, the problem seems to be with PDF and Doc files.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Which Nuget are you using?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Xam.Plugin.FilePicker

Comment: That one is outdate and no longer maintained. Please have a look at this one: https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows and see if it solves your problem

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I just tried this, but it is still doing the same thing, it is giving a blank DataArray, is there a problem with the way I am doing it in the above code?

Comment: Did you also check out the beta packages? The code should be fine. From what path are you trying to open the file? Do you have the right permissions?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I just tried the newest beta, I have the right permissions (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and the path is from a google drive. It's still doing the same thing. It can get file path fine but cannot get the DataArray

Comment: I think there is already a PR for this that should fix it. I just have to check it. Anyhow, I think this belongs on Github with the project and not here on SO :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis it gives the path as "/document/acc=3;doc=2", is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I have put as an issue on GitHub